# Homomorphic encryption key switching

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I understand the general idea of key switching, but I would like to know when it is used. Sometimes it is referred to as same thing as relinearisation(after multiplication), but is key switching also used when rotating (batched ciphertexts)? If so, how similar to each other are different key switching situations? I am interested in the most popular schemes(BFV, BGV, CKKS).

Thanks for help!